# Why is if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have this little example script. It gets a file from a HTML an uploads it to the server. That part works just fine. Please see the script below.

I would like to take some action if no file is selected in the form. I thought the following would evaluate to false if no file was selected in the HTML form, but it seams to be always true.

```
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
```

Either a file is selected or not 'Text to print' is returned.

What am I missing here?

Any hint is appreciated.

Best regards
Kresten

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

app = Flask(__name__)
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = 'static'
configure_uploads(app, photos)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
    filename = photos.url(request.files['photo'])
    fil = request.files['photo']
    return 'Text to print'

  return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The HTML template:

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url_for('upload') }}">
    <input type=file name=photo>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(Thanks to Danila for saving my day)

Comment: could you add your template to question?

Comment: Its in the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `photo` always will be in `request.files`, but `filename` not(can be empty string). Just change condition to:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.files['photo'].filename:
    filename = photos.url(request.files['photo'])
    fil = request.files['photo']
    return 'Text to print'

  return render_template('upload.html')
```